# How can we transfer the files from one drive to aonther in the system

Tags: windows-7

A puzzle of How to transfer the files from one drive to another without using the mouse in the system?

Comment: Use the keyboard?

Comment: Before there were touch screen gestures, there were pointing devices like the mouse. Before the mouse & graphical user interface were invented, there were just keyboards. Early application software introduced popular keyboard shortcuts, like Akina's answer. Before that, there was just a command language (which people still use, and it is used in .bat files). For example, you could use `copy` in a command that also specifies the source you want to copy and the destination. With a GUI interface, like Windows, you would need a keyboard shortcut to open a command line window.  See MS-DOS commands.

Answer (score 1):

1. Press Win-R.
2. Type source drive/folder framed by double-quotes.
3. Press Enter - explorer window with source folder opened.
4. Press Win-R.
5. Type destination drive/folder framed by double-quotes.
6. Press Enter - explorer window with destination folder opened.
7. Switch to source window using Alt-Tab (press Alt, press Tab as much as needed, release Alt).
8. Press Tab until some (first) folder/file selected in source window. Select folder/file for copying using arrow keys (shift-arrow to select a solid block of files/folders).
9. Press Ctrl-C.
10. Switch to Destonation window using Alt-Tab.
11. Press Ctrl-V. Copying started.
12. Repeat 7-11 until all folders/files copied.
13. Close windows (switch by Alt-Tab, close by Alt-F4).